# parallax, scrolling background of a single div

Tags: jquery, background, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, parallax

```
 <div id="first-div" style="width:960px; height:1200px;"> 
<div id="second-div" style="width:500px; border:solid 1px; height:30px; background:#333;"> Scroll Background </div>
</ldiv>
```

here is a div code , I want to move background of second div from left to right, when first div scroll down.

**Detail:** At beginning second div background should be white but when first div scroll down ,second div's black background should appear from left to right by using css3 or jquery.